# Find and extract a varying substring in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string:

```
a = 'foobarbizzbazz;adurl=http://google.com" foobarbizzbazz'
```

How do I extract the substring in between `;adurl=` and `"`? This substring would be assigned to a URL object. The string, and interior URL, varies each time so I need to extract an unknown part of the string.

I am unable to figure out a way to use `begin_with`, `end_with`, or `contains` to get the desired output.

Comment: Since you appear to be learning, I'll just point you in the right direction so you can figure it out and get the most for your miles:

You'll essentially convert the string to an array, then iterate over it (google "enumerable"). Use a regular expression (<= google) to then find the item in the array that is a URL.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's important to show your attempt to solve a problem. It's better for us to correct your code than it is for us to write code that is totally unrelated to surrounding code in your program. You'll have to shoehorn in the new code which can introduce new problems.

Answer (score 2):

This'll find it:

```
a = 'foobarbizzbazz;adurl=http://google.com" foobarbizzbazz'
a[/adurl=([^"]+)"/, 1] # => "http://google.com"
```

It's using [String's `[]` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) to search the string. `,1` tells it to return the first capture-group.

`[^"]+` in Regular Expressions creates a "[character class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes)" and means "one or more characters *NOT* `"`", so in effect it's finding the occurrence of "adurl=", capturing all characters up to the first double-quote, and returning them.

Creating a [URI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html) object then is very easy:

```
require 'uri'

url = 'foobarbizzbazz;adurl=http://google.com" foobarbizzbazz'
uri = URI.parse(url[/adurl=([^"]+)"/, 1]) # => #<URI::HTTP http://google.com>
```

At that point you can take advantage of URI's methods to manipulate the URL to your heart's content.

Comment: Thanks you The Tin Man, That worked !! You are awesome. I appreciate your time to share that info.

Answer (score -1):

Try regular expressions:

```
regexp = /;adurl=(.*)\\/
regexp.match(a)[1] # --> http://google.com
```

Test it here http://rubular.com/

Comment: its not working for me. i see the following `irb(main):010:0> regexp = /;adurl=(.*)\\/
/;adurl=(.*)\\/
irb(main):011:0> regexp.match(a)[1]
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
 from (irb):11
 from /Users/pradeep/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'`